# Yiibooster editable widget inside popover widget

Tags: php, yii, widget, yii-booster

I'm building website using yii 1.1 framework and Clevertech YiiBooster extension.

Is there an easy way to render few "editable field" widgets inside the popover widget ?

Please see the code below. Any suggestions are welcome.

Main view:

```
....

$this->widget(
                            'booster.widgets.TbButton', array(
                                'label' => 'Right popover',
                                'context' => 'warning',
                                'buttonType' => 'button',
                                'size' => 'extra_small',
                                'htmlOptions' => array(
                                    'id' => uniqid(),
                                    'data-html' => true,
                                    'data-title' => 'A Title',
                                    'data-placement' => 'right',
                                    'data-content' => $this->renderPartial('VIEW', array('data'=>$data), true, true),
                                    'data-toggle' => 'popover'
                                ),
                            )
                        );

....
```

partial view:

```
 $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbEditableField', array(
     'type' => 'text',
     'model' => $survey,
     'attribute' => 'text',
     'pk' => 'pk',
     'name' => 'name',
     'text' =>  '',
     'url' => $this->createUrl('controller/method/'), //url for submit data
     'title' => 'text',
     'placement' => 'right',
     'id' => uniqid()),true);

$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbEditableField', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'model' => $survey,
    'attribute' => 'text',
    'pk' => 'pk',
    'name' => 'name',
    'text' =>  '',
    'url' => $this->createUrl('controller/method/'), //url for submit data
    'title' => 'text',
    'placement' => 'right',
    'id' => uniqid()),true);

$this->widget('booster.widgets.TbEditableField', array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'model' => $survey,
    'attribute' => 'text',
    'pk' => 'pk',
    'name' => 'name',
    'text' =>  '',
    'url' => $this->createUrl('controller/method/'), //url for submit data
    'title' => 'text',
    'placement' => 'right',
    'id' => uniqid()),true);
```

Comment: have you tried above code? what errors are you getting?

Comment: Yes, I tried that code. There is no javascript for widgets inside the partial view.